# In React.js, How can I get return data from smart contract method including event and emit?

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, react, smart-contract-wallets

I have smart contract server function and that function including emit and event.

```
event TokenMinted(
        address indexed _recipient, 
        uint256 indexed _tokenId
        );

 function mintToken(address to, address[] memory bundle) public {
        // Mint new token
        uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
        .........
        // Emit TokenMinted event
        emit TokenMinted(to, tokenId);
        // Increase the token counter
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
    }
```

Not I'm going to call this function and hope to get tokenId.

But In my React frontend code, I can't find method to get tokenId.

```
export const mintToken = async (contract, to, address) => {
  let tokenId = await contract.mintToken(to, address);
  console.log('contracts', contract)
  // console.log('contract.events', contract.filters.TokenMinted())
  //get the latest blocknumber

  return tokenId;
}
```

The contract generated like this.

```
new ethers.Contract(ROCI_MINTER_ADDR, ROCI_MINTER_ABI, library.getSigner());
```

How can I get this value correctly?
Thanks for attention.

Comment: I would recommend adding a `getBalance` view function which returns an array of ids that the caller owns. Then you can use this function to see if there are any changes.

Answer (score 0):

that is not neither a `view` or a `pure` function, so you probably are looking  for something like this (check [here for documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send)):

```
let tx = await contract.mintToken(to, address).send({from: '0x123123123123'});

let events = tx.receipt.events
console.log(events)
```

Comment: But I got error 'not found send function'.

Comment: @BackendandFrontendDeveloper are you using the basic web3.js library?

Comment: "web3-react": "^5.0.5"  "@web3-react/core": "^6.1.9",
    "@web3-react/injected-connector": "^6.0.7",
This is my package.json file

Answer (score 0):

The latest docs says to do the following:

`contract.events.TokenMinted().on('data', this.contractEventHandler )`

it depends on the version of web3 you have. Here are the docs. https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth-contract.html#id50

Note; I was having errors when I tried to locally copy and manipulate a react state variable in the contractEventHandler, however, doing the following worked for me `setState({tokens:[...this.state.tokens,token]});`